# pick up at one location and return it at another

Tags: ellipsis, coordination

If I am talking to a car rental agent whose company has many branch offices, could I use the following sentence?
I'd like to know if it is natural to leave out the object of **pick up**.

> 1. Can I pick up at one location and return **it** at another?
> 2. Can I pick up from one location and return **a car** to another?

I'm thinking about examples like "He bought and ate a burger," where the 
object "burger" is shared by "bought" as well as "ate." Do you know 
the same process cannot work in the car rental example?

Answer (score 3):

I would say that one could dispense with nouns and pronouns altogether, if talking (or writing) to an agency which dealt specifically with hiring cars :

> May I collect and return to different branches ?

... is quite sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentences sound natural but require an *it* to make them grammatically correct:

> Can I pick **it** up at one location and return it at another?
>
> Can I pick **a car** up from one location and return **it** to another?

Comment: "Can I **it** pick up" should be "Can I pick **it** up"

Comment: Millions of native speakers ask *Can I pick up at one location and drop off at another?*  using the verbs intransitively to refer to the two basic activities of car rental.  No object is needed for this question to be grammatical.

Comment: I agree that the pronoun is required in order for the sentence to sound natural. But in the second sentence, if you're not going to use **it** in both parts of the sentence, I would use **the car** in the first part and **it** in the second part. Specifying the pronoun *before* what it refers to is unnatural.

Comment: @DManokhin I have taken the liberty of changing your second example to read: **Can I pick the car up from one location and return it to another?** because, logically, you have to refer to **the car** before you can refer to **it**.. At the same time, I have marked your answer up. It's not customary to amend somebody's answer and I apologise for intruding in this manner. You can reverse my changes if you choose.

Comment: I'm thinking about examples like "He bought and ate a burger," where the 
object "burger" is shared by "bought" as well as "ate." Do you know 
the same process cannot work in the car rental example?